# Folders are not fetchable at Hostinger shared business hosting plan

Tags: javascript, fetch, hosting, http-status-code-403

I've nearly bought a domain. After that a shared business hosting plan for the domain. And now I am able to fetch files in folders using Javascript, but I am unable to fetch folders to get list of files. It is returning 403 error which is forbidden code even if I've allowed to read and write to that folder. My website is in /domain.com/public_html folder. And my files are in /domain.com/public_html/files folder.

I've tried to enable and disable permissions for files and folders. Also, I tried to use Fix File Ownership tool. And also, I've turned on and off Folder Index Manager.